# Is Heathcare IT taboo?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've been monitoring [the heathcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it) SO and I'd really like it to take off so I can rant and rave about the government somewhere.

Today (actually yesterday) [CMS](https://www.cms.gov/NursingHomeQualityInits/30_NHQIMDS30TechnicalInformation.asp) (part of the American Health and Human Services) was supposed to release a file that we were supposed to have in our update.  However, that file never got released.

I wanted to ask about how I could get a [redress of grievances](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12298/when-the-government-is-the-problem-closed) but was unceremoniously slammed by people who probably had no idea what I was talking about.

So, did we reject [this edict](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/) or just ignore it?

Comment: I could have sworn I saw 2 views and -3 points.

Comment: Do your downvotes mean healthcare it is offtopic or have y'all forgotten how to use this website?

Comment: I mean seriously, do you all ignore the "If you downvote, please say how this could be improved" message.  And you dare accuse me of not knowing how the system works!

Comment: @Peter:  You don't know how the system works.  Keep the rants off-site.  Don't confuse a problem with a government website with healthcare IT.  Don't assume that people who disagree with you probably don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @David, that's exactly what I was assuming!

Comment: @Peter:  "...was unceremoniously slammed by people who probably had no idea what I was talking about."  These people were disagreeing with you as to whether a rant about a government website and a request for files belong on programmers.se.

Answer (score 13):

The issue isn't the topic of Healthcare IT.

Programmers.SE is a site for questions and answers about programming related issues. Your question isn't programming related: you're ranting about your experience with the government, and tangentially asking for a file you couldn't get from them.

Rants, in any form, are not allowed across the Stack Exchange network. If you're looking for an outlet to air your frustration, I'd suggest a blog.